# Can Nerdtree handle symbolic link when sync path?

Tags: vim, ctags, nerdtree

I am using `ctags` to generate tags and put `set tags+=~/.vim/tags/cpp`(just followed [this wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion)) in `.vimrc`.In my `vimrc` file there is also the setting like below so I can auto sync the nerdtree viewer for the current file(see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/195022/vim-how-to-synchronize-nerdtree-with-current-opened-tab-file-path/474298#474298)):

```
" returns true iff is NERDTree open/active
function! rc:isNTOpen()        
  return exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && (bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1)
endfunction

" returns true iff focused window is NERDTree window
function! rc:isNTFocused()     
  return -1 != match(expand('%'), 'NERD_Tree') 
endfunction 

" calls NERDTreeFind iff NERDTree is active, current window contains a modifiable file, and we're not in vimdiff
function! rc:syncTree()
  if &modifiable && rc:isNTOpen() && !rc:isNTFocused() && strlen(expand('%')) > 0 && !&diff
    NERDTreeFind
    wincmd p
  endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call rc:syncTree()
```

The problem lies in that `~/.vim` is actually a symbolic link to another folder(So I can manage all my dotfiles using git or other VCSs easily). When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to look for a definition(whose tag information is in *~/.vim/tags/cpp*), there would be always the error:

```
detected while processing function rc:syncTree..<SNR>15_findAndRevealPath..102:
line    2:
E605: Exception not caught: NERDTree.InvalidArgumentsError: /home/hongxuchen/.vim/tags/cpp_src/stl_iterator.h should be under /home/hongxuchen/data_backup/dotfiles/_vim/tags/cpp_src
```

Does it mean that I have to use **`set tags+=/real/path/to/cpp`** instead in `vimrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vim, the `resolve()` function can process symbolic links. Try replacing in `plugin/NERD_tree.vim`

```
function! s:findAndRevealPath()
    try
        let p = s:Path.New(expand("%:p"))
```

with

```
function! s:findAndRevealPath()
    try
        let p = s:Path.New(resolve(expand("%:p")))
```

If that works, I'd send a patch to the plugin's author.

Comment: It works(at least for my vim7.3, which is a deb package in Ubuntu12.04 amd64),thanks so much! Please send a pull request to him:-)

Comment: With "I'd", I meant "I would [recommend you to]". I have no system to reproduce, and it's mainly in your interest, so please send this feedback to the author yourself. The bug tracker is [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues).

Comment: Actually I am not using the author's [latest version on master branch](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) on github, but a mirror from vim-scripts and the src of the plugin is almost [this one](https://github.com/vim-scripts/The-NERD-tree/blob/master/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L2558).(in fact I'm using _vundle_ to manage the plugins). It seems that [the refactor-open branch of nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/refactor-open/plugin/NERD_tree.vim#L2798) contains similar code, but I don't know whether the symbolic link problem has been fixed.

Comment: Well, just open an issue then and point to this question; I think the author will extract the (rather simple) issue and the fix, and know best what to do with it, and where to apply it.

Comment: It saved my day, really appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

While it is not strictly an answer to your question, my answer will certainly help fix your underlying problem.

I have my "real" `vimrc` under version control in `~/.vim/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc` is not a symlink because I *hate* symlinks. Instead, `~/.vimrc` is a regular file with only one line:

```
runtime vimrc
```

Comment: I would like to back up this suggestion, since I share @romainl's stance on symbolic links, and use the same workaround for my `vimrc`-file for a long time (without any issues).